# I am running 12.04 on a Toshiba Satellite A205-S4607, and everything freezes almost right away

Tags: 12.04

When I run:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install octave`

it froze about 5 minutes into that. Now when I boot up it freezes almost instantly after I log in. It's happened 3 times in a row now.

Switching to a different workspace doesn't unfreeze it.

I think I may have to do this:

`i915.modeset=1`

but I don't know where to do that.

Also, I think I may need to paste a log file here but I'm not sure which one.

Comment: I am hesitant to ask, but did you pull power or do a hard reboot when it froze the first time?

Comment: If you did, you may need to reinstall/repair something seriously.

Comment: Yes, I just powered it off. I don't have anything important on the machine though. What should I do now? What should I have done?

Comment: Right now, you probably should just reinstall.

Comment: What you should have done is 1) Try hitting CTRL-C multiple times to stop it; 2) let it sit overnight and see if it ever finishes (if option 1 doesn't work)